# Polygonal scatter diagram with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, distance, diagram, similarity

I have a matrix of `N` observations and `F` features. Among the `N` observations, 5 represent reference samples that I wish to compare with others (with distance or similarity measures). Depending on how close the `N` features are from the 5 references, I would like to plot them on a polygonal diagram to have a better perception of how they are distributed between the 5 cases (i.e. how distant they are).
This is an example of result I would like to get:

[image]

Each corner represent a reference while black dots are the samples to locate between such references. How can I produce this type of diagram in python?

Also, would it be possible to produce such diagram by modulating the number of corners (lower or higher than 5)?

Comment: can you provide a minimal example (data+code) to reproduce a graph?

Comment: yes, just plot a line between the reference points and you will make the polygon. then plot the rest of the points as black points

Comment: Without data and an actual use case, this question is much too broad. Basically, for each observation you assign a weight for each feature, and normalize these such that they sum to 1.  Then you just use these to calculate a weighted sum of the corners.  In many cases, most dots will accumulate near the center. The most crucial step is assigning the weights, which is very subjective and problem dependant.

Comment: Also, with more than three reference points in 2 dimensions, you won't be able to accurately place all other points while satisfying all distance constraints, at least not in general (unless your reference points happen to lie exactly on the corners of a regular pentagon in some well-behaved space, i.e. not defined by your reference points). Your idea is (probably) mathematically impossible.